# using awk or sed extract first character of each column and store it in a separate file

Tags: input, awk

I have a file like below

```
AT AT AG AG
GC GC GG GC
```

i want to extract first and last character of every col n store them in two different files

File1:

```
A A A A
G G G G
```

File2:

```
T T G G
C C G C
```

My input file is very large. Is it a way that i can do it in awk or sed

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
gawk '{
    print gensub(/.( |$)/,"","g") > "file1"
    print gensub(/(^| )./,"","g") > "file2"
}' file
```

You can do similar in any awk with gsub() and a couple of variables.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

write in test.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

 BEGIN {

 #   FS = "[\s]+"
     outfile_head="file1"
     outfile_tail="file2"
 }

     {
         num = NF
         for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
             printf "%s ", substr($i, 0, 1) >> outfile_head
             printf "%s ", substr($i, length($i), 1) >> outfile_tail
         }
     }
```

then you run this:
./test.awk file

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do in two passes:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]\)[^ ]/\1/g' file > file1
sed 's/[^ ]\([^ ]\)/\1/g' file > file2
```

Doing it in one pass is a challenge...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1:** Modified for your multiple line edit.

You could write a perl script and pass in the file names if you plan to edit it and share it. This loops through the file only once and does not require storing the file in memory.

File "seq.pl":

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(F1,">>$ARGV[1]");
open(F2,">>$ARGV[2]");
open(DATA,"$ARGV[0]");
while($line=<DATA>) {
  $line =~ s/(\r|\n)+//g;
  @pairs = split(/\s/, $line);
  for $pair(@pairs) {
    @bases = split(//,$pair);
    print F1 $bases[0]." ";
    print F2 $bases[length($bases)-1]." ";
  }
  print F1 "\n";
  print F2 "\n";
}
close(F1);
close(F2);
close(DATA);
```

Execute it like so:

```
perl seq.pl full.seq f1.seq f2.seq
```

File "full.seq":

```
AT AT AG AG
GC GC GG GC
AT AT GC GC
```

File "f1.seq":

```
A A A A
G G G G
A A G G
```

File "f2.seq":

```
T T G G
C C G C
T T C C
```